# javascript not working with Bootstrap/rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

I am working on a rails app embedded with Bootstrap. The styles are working just fine with bootstrap, but I can't seem to get javascript or jquery working. I went into the application.js file under the javascripts folder and put in to require jquery

```html
//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .


//=requre jquery
```

When I tried to do it with javascript it gave me an error message that it could not find the page I was wokring on, Which is titled signin.html.erb.

My issue is that I can't get the scripts to run I can't even get it to do a simple alert

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    var Login = username



              if login == username

                document.getElementById("home").onclick = function(){

                    Document.getElementById.href = ("/pages/home").
                    
                }


            else


                document.getElementById("home").onclick = function{

                    alert("an error was found please try again")

                }


                alert("Jquery is working")
```

I was just wondering wether It's a rails problem or a javascript problem

Comment: `//=requre jquery`  typo

Comment: Also as a side note, your application.js is packaging all those files into a single file, `application.js`.  Since that file includes the jquery, you should include that file on your page, and not include jquery directly.

Comment: Thank you i didn't see that

Comment: And from your snippet, it does not look like your javascript is between `<script></script>` tags

Comment: `if login == username` is also missing the `()` around the expression.

Comment: `//=requre jquery` should probably be a the top of your `application.js`. Your dev tools js console will probably give you an idea of what's wrong.